# Bogoliubov transformation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, bose-einstein-condensate

In the book "Bose-Einstein condensate", they're doing a Bogoliubov transformation:

$
a_p=u_pb_p+v_{-p}^\star b_{-p}^\dagger\\
a_p^\dagger=u_p^\star b_p^\dagger+v_{-p}b_{-p}
$

Where the untransformed Hamiltonian reads:

$
H=g\frac{N^2}{2V}+\sum \frac{p^2}{2m}a_p^\dagger a_p+\frac{1}{2}\sum\left(2 a_p^\dagger a_p+a_p^\dagger a_{-p}^\dagger+a_p a_{-p}+\frac{mgn}{p^2}\right)
$

Let's focus on the terms $a_p^\dagger a_{-p}^\dagger+a_p a_{-p}$. When I use the transformations from above, I will assume that:
$
a_{-p}=u_{-p}b_{-p}+v_{p}^\star b_{p}^\dagger
$

(Is that right?) 
When I'm doing so I and only have a look at the terms with $b_p b_{-p}$ I get:

$\frac{gn}{2}\left(v_{-p}v_p+u_pu_{-p}\right)$

Pitaevskii has a different result here, namely:

$\frac{gn}{2}\left(|v_p|^2+|u_p|^2\right)$

Where is the mistake?

Best

Comment: Are you dealing with a real, scalar field? I think the needed condition then follows from requiring reality of the field. In any case, your question seems to be of the form: I assume $X$ and get a wrong answer. Why? ...perhaps reconsider assuming $X$?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I only try to understand the calculation in the book of Pitaevskii and Stringari. The sense behind this calculation is to diagonalise the Hamiltonian above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Bogoliubov transformation, it is the case that
$$u_{-p} = u^*_p,$$
and
$$v_{-p} = v^*_p,$$
so your result is correct. In fact, if you move on to basically the next equation, they assume that both $u$ and $v$ are *real*, in which case
$$u_{-p} = u^*_p = u_p,$$
as mentioned by `Mark Mitchison` in a comment below this answer.

---

And incidentally, yes it is true that
$$a_{-p} = u_{-p}b_p + v^*_{p}b^{\dagger}_p$$

Comment: Note that one can usually assume the even simpler condition that $u_{-p} = u^*_p = u_p$, and likewise for $v_p$.

Comment: @MarkMitchison. I was actually just about to add that detail to the post, as I decided to quickly look up what they actually did in their book, and they go on to make the assumption that the $u$'s and $v$'s are real.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answers! And why is $u_{-p}=u_p^\star$?.

Comment: @QuantumMechanics. I can't quite remember how that comes about. I think it's something that you show along the way; that is, somewhere during the calculation, you realize that you are forced to make that assumption in order that certain terms cancel in order that the Hamiltonian is at the end diagonalized. I'll look over some old notes if I get the time and update the answer.

Comment: @QuantumMechanics. Actually, I think the answer is pretty straight-forward: the sum over $p$ is invariant with respect to the transformation $p\to-p$, so the functions should respect this symmetry. Anyway, if you look at equation 4.28 (and 4.31) in the book, you'll see that the expressions for $u$ and $v$ are strictly functions of $p^2$.