# Sign of momentum doesn't affect Bogoliubov coefficients in Bogoliubov transformation for BEC

Tags: condensed-matter, operators, hamiltonian, second-quantization, bose-einstein-condensate

I'm running into some issues with the deriving Bogoliubov transformation. Specifically, in order to diagonalize the Hamiltonian

$$\begin{align}H = \sum_p \frac{p^2}{2m} \hat a^\dagger_p \hat a_p + \frac{1}{2V}\Big[ U_0 N_0^2 + 4 N_0 U_0 \sum_{p\neq 0} \hat a^\dagger_p \hat a_p  + N_0 U_0 \sum_{p\neq 0}(\hat a^\dagger_p\hat a^\dagger_{-p} + \hat a_p \hat a_{-p}) \Big]
\end{align}$$

one can use the Bogoliubov transformation:
$$\begin{align}
\hat a_k^\dagger = u_k \hat \alpha_{k}^\dagger - v_k \hat \alpha_{-k}\\
\hat a_k = u_k \hat \alpha_k - v_k \hat \alpha_{-k}^\dagger
\end{align}$$

However, in the derivation, it seems one has to assume that $u_{-p} = u_p$ and $v_{-p} = v_p$. Now in hindsight, once one knows the equation for $u_p$ and $v_p$, this is obvious. However, what is the justification for making this assumption before one finds the answer?

Comment: [Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/216364/) (if not a duplicate).

Comment: Also, give an exact reference. I.e. book title, edition, chapter, page number, equation number...

Comment: Hi @march, I did see that question, but I did not understand your comment that since "the sum over p is invariant with respect to the transformation p→−p, so the functions should respect this symmetry." $a_p$ and $a_{-p}$ are distinct operators, so when we expand them with the bogoliubov transform, it's not obvious to me that the two should have the same bogoliubov coefficients.

Comment: @Zonova Yeah, this is one of the reasons I just linked to it rather than marking it a duplicate.  I'm pretty sure what I said is *true*, that you can use the invariance $p\to -p$ to *show* that those coefficients should be the same, but I haven't gone through that calculation in a very long time and don't plan on doing it now.